# Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied "

Tags: email, mailgun, laravel-7

I am getting this error Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Relaying denied  " when I try using mailgun and laravel 7 to send emails. But I do not know what to do

Comment: please accept my answer if you find it correct

Comment: Kindly paster your code, we have a look you might be missing something. Also, Laravel changed from MAIL_DRIVER to MAIL_MAILER

Answer (score 41):

Make sure you have `MAIL_MAILER=mailgun` instead of `MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun`

**It changed in Laravel 7+.**

Use something like this:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=example
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mailgun-domain.example
MAILGUN_SECRET=example-key-here
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Boom. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Abeer Sul! I am getting the same error on my webpage. But I am using October CMS and a plugin called "Magic Forms". Could you help me with it?

Comment: Unfortunately @AbishekH I never used it before

Comment: @DarrenMurphy, you don't have to downvote it. There might be something else you need to change in your code. I faced many issues like everyone, this code fixed it

Comment: I had to exclude the `MAILGUN_ENDPOINT` I think it is only for EU

Answer (score 3):

Check your `config/mail.php` file, to see whether MAIL_DRIVER or MAIL_MAILER is an env value. Then set MAIL_DRIVER or MAIL_MAILER in the .env file.

By default, emails are sent via SMTP. If you have set, for instance, MAILGUN_DOMAIN and MAILGUN_SECRET, expecting to us the API, this will not be the case, if the MAIL_DRIVE/MAIL_MAILER is not set up mailgun.